# capture RTSP stream from IP camera ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the following command to get the frames from RTSP h264 codec. I could not able to get the frames from the ip camera.

```
$ ffmpeg -i rtsp://xxxx:yyy@192.168.1.yy:xx/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/120 img%03d.jpg
```

My output

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --disable-yasm

  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100

  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101

  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100

  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101

  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100

  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100

  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100

  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

[rtsp @ 0x2dba3a0] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.
    Last message repeated 5 times

[rtsp @ 0x2dba3a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size

Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 
'rtsp://xx:yy@192.168.1.xx:yy/tcp/av0_0':

  Metadata:

    title           : streamed by the RTSP server

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc

    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s

Output #0, image2, to 'img%03d.jpg':

Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 1G -probesize 50M -i rtsp://xxxx:yyy@192.168.1.yy:xx/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/120 img%03d.jpg My output`

Comment: It didn't work. Got the same output. I can see two streams both audio and video. I need only video stream to get frames. Is there any conflict between those streams?

Comment: Do you know the resolution and frame rate of the video?

Comment: Thanks Mulvya. I actually got it now with this. ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xx:yy@192.168.1.ee:fd/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 hello/img%03d.png

Answer (score 5):

I got it working with the following command, finally. I missed out using `rtsp_transport`.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://xx:yy@192.168.1.ee:fd/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 hello/img%03d.png
```